# Firestore how to query documents chronologically

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, querying

I understand that unlike Firebase Realtime DB, there isn't a built in method for querying Firestore documents chronologically.

Other than adding a timestamp field to each document, is there another elegant way to achieve that?

Apparently it isn't recommended to name documents in an ascending names ([Do not use monotonically increasing document IDs](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/best-practices))